# Bootstrap-Margin issue

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm currently learning the basics of bootstrap, and am having issues with the margin-auto. I am working with a navbar and trying to position it use ml-auto to separate it from the brand (pushing the navbar to the right of the page) Unfortunately, I cannot figure out why it's not working for me. I've done some searching on getbootstrap.com site, but am finding nothing that helps. Can you please help? Thank you! :)

````
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="">tindog</a>
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">

            <a class="nav-link" href="">Contact</a>
        </li>
<li class="nav-item">

        <a class="nav-link" href="">Pricing</a>
        </li>
<li class="nav-item">

       <a class="nav-link" href="">Download</a>
        </li>        
    </ul>
</nav>```
````

Comment: What version of bootstrap do you use?

Comment: bootstrap 5. I apologize. I literally just found something from an older article that it has changed to ms-auto. Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Simple put the m-0 and p-0 inside the navbar class. hope so this way your issue will be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap includes an .mx-auto class for horizontally centring fixed-width block level content.

Use mx-auto

Refer: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/spacing/